# Drawable with bitmap over

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

Hello I'm trying to achieve this look but with no success maybe you could help me out and Thank you for you time!

*Desired look:*

[image]

And my approach was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="#cf6c6c6c"
                android:startColor="#53414141"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:gravity="right"
        android:height="10dp"
        android:width="10dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/flag_uk"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to draw the image dynamically with a fixed images size and not putting the different graphics inside the  `res/drawable*` folders?

Comment: if you have adobe illustrator installed, create this in adobe illustrator, it's easy to work with vector graphics. Then save as svg, there's svg to xml converter online. You can get any desired result.

Comment: @AmirDe I will try it thank you

Comment: @Philipp no there are no reasons just tested the outcome.

Comment: You're welcome, @Sz-NikaJanos here is the svg to xml converter link http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below drawable xml code:

**Drawable file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:right="25dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="#cf6c6c6c"
                android:startColor="#53414141"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="10dp"
        android:left="90dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:right="15dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/flag_uk"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And use this drawable to `TextView` or `LinearLayout`, I am using LinearLayout:

**Layout XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#88ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="coin"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        <gradient
            android:angle="45"
            android:endColor="#cf6c6c6c"
            android:startColor="#53414141"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>


<item android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:height="10dp"
    android:width="10dp">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/flag_uk"/>
</item>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/some_drawable"
    android:text="coin"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
```

[image] Photo is zoomed hence pixalated